# Exclude field from full-text search

Tags: mongodb

I need to do the full text search in the MongoDB (version 2.4). I use the following fragment of code.

```
DBObject textSearchCommand = new BasicDBObject();
textSearchCommand.put("text", "profile");
textSearchCommand.put("search", pattern);
textSearchCommand.put("limit", searchLimit);
textSearchCommand.put("filter",new BasicDBObject("personInfo", new BasicDBObject("$ne",null)));
CommandResult commandResult = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(textSearchCommand);
BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList) commandResult.get("results");
```

It works well but I want to exclude one field (person picture data) from the text search.

**Note**: I don't want to exclude this field from the result. I want that MongoDB does not search in this field.

Comment: Cannot be done as the fields of the index are all defined on index creation and there is no option to "choose" them on query form. You could assign "weights" to the index to make the field "less important", but again that is not tunable "per query" and is defined in the index again. Depending on what your "text search" is actually doing then `.aggregate()` or `.mapReduce()` might be a better approach to assign a "score" for which to order results on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which fields to search in is determined when you [create the text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/). When you only want the text index to apply to selected fields, you need to provide these fields at creation like this for example:

```
db.articles.createIndex(
                       {
                         title: "text",
                         synopsis: "text",
                         content: "text",
                         tags: "text"
                       }
                     )
```

When this is not an option for some reason (like when you don't know all possible field names which might be relevant for text search), an (admittedly dirty) workaround could be to store the non-searchable content in a different data-type than a string, for example as binary data.

Comment: If one wanted a filtering option for the client to search specific fields this approach is problematic unless MongoDB allows you to create multiple text indexes?

Comment: @badger110 you have a soloution? I also need to give that possiblity to the client - fulltext search on individual fields

Comment: @Suisse MongoDB only allows one text index per collection, and a text search won't tell you which field triggered each result. A possible workaround is to create an additional collection for each field you want to index. The documents in those collections would have the _id of the document they belong to and the content of that one field.

Comment: @Philipp I wish you were a Clown and that was a joke. Thank you. :D hehe